# Login with Firebase and then login to my API with Firebase JWT token

Tags: android, firebase, jwt, token

My application consists from four parts. Web (Vue.js), Android app, Firebase and API. Web or Android app need to login to Firebase, but API need to know that login is valid. I though that Firebase send JWT token which can be decoded by any application which have Firebase secret. But I am not sure if it works this way.

Is it possible to get JWT token from Web or Android app which did authentication via Firebase and decode this token in API. I mean without any connection between API and Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Most Firebase SDKs send the ID token of the user that is signed in to Firebase Authentication to the Firebase backend with either every call or when they first establish the connection.

If you're communicating with your own backend API, there is usually no Firebase SDK involved - so the ID token will not be added automatically. Instead you can [add it to the call yourself](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients), and then [code the ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) in your server-side code.